# Python, sharing mysql connection in multiple functions - pass connection or cursor?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am opening mysql connection in the main function and use that connection in multiple functions called by the main function.

**Is there anything wrong with passing cursor from main function instead of passing the connection?**

I.e.:

**Pass in cursor from main function**

```
def main():
    conn = pymysql.connect(...)
    with conn as cursor:
        func1(cursor)
        func2(cursor)
    conn.close()

def func1(cursor):
    cursor.execute('select ...')

def func2(cursor):
    cursor.execute('insert ...')
```

**Pass in connection from main function**

```
def main():
    conn = pymysql.connect(...)
    func1(conn)
    func2(conn)
    conn.close()

def func1(conn):
    with conn as cursor:
        cursor.execute('select ...')

def func2(conn):
    with conn as cursor:
        cursor.execute('insert ...')
```

Comment: I'm more wondering if there's anything wrong with passing cursor, that's my preferred method, as it requires less code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer comes from [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter): Pass cursor.

This also leads to a slightly shorter code. In this case, it's pretty trivial, but sometimes it may be a lot (e.g., passing a database name vs. passing a cursor).