# Should I pass Database connection or Cursor to a class

Tags: python, pyodbc, vertica

I'm writing a Python script to move data from production db to dev db. I'm using `vertica-python` (something very similar to `pyodbc`) for db connection and `airflow` for scheduling.

The script is divided into two files, one for DAG and one for the actual migration job. I use `try-except-finally` block for all SQL execution functions in the migration job:

```
try:
    # autocommit set to False
    # Execute a SQL script
except DatabaseError:
    # Logging information
    # Rollback
finally:
    # autocommit set to False
```

You can see that setting `autocommit` and `Rollback` needs to access the connection, and executing a SQL script needs to access the cursor. The current solution is to simply create two DB connections in DAG and pass them to the migration script. But I also read from a Stackoverflow post that I should pass only the cursor:

[Python, sharing mysql connection in multiple functions - pass connection or cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233570/python-sharing-mysql-connection-in-multiple-functions-pass-connection-or-curs)

My question is: Is it possible to only pass the `cursor` from the DAG to the migration script, and still retain the ability to `rollback` and setting `autocommit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the `autocommit` setting via the Cursor:

```py
>>> import pyodbc
>>> cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=mssqlLocal")
>>> cnxn.autocommit
False
>>> crsr = cnxn.cursor()
>>> crsr.connection.autocommit = True
>>> cnxn.autocommit
True
>>>
```

pyodbc also provides [commit()](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#commit) and [rollback()](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#rollback) methods on the Cursor object, but be aware that they affect all cursors created by the same connection, i.e., `crsr.rollback()` is exactly the same as calling `cnxn.rollback()`.